# Changing the collection in observer in Magento 1 issue

Tags: magento-1, event-observer, grid

I added a new column to my sales order grid and it works perfectly. If I go the the recent orders grid from the customer view it doesn't work . I got an error message:
`Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'c.increment_id' in 'field list'`.

This is how I added the new column to my sales order grid:

```
public function beforeBlockToHtml(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $grid = $observer->getBlock();
        /**
         * Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid
         */
        if ($grid instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid) {
            $grid->addColumnAfter(
                'customer_increment_id',
                [
                    'header' => Mage::helper('ffm_codebin')->__('Customer Inc.'),
                    'index'  => 'customer_increment_id',
                    'filter_index' => 'c.increment_id'
                ],
                'entity_id'
            );
        }
    }
public function beforeCollectionLoad(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $collection = $observer->getCollection();
        if(!isset($collection)){
            return;
        }
        if($collection instanceof Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Grid_Collection){

            $collection->getSelect()->join(['c' => $collection->getTable('customer/entity')]
                ,'main_table.customer_id = c.entity_id', ['customer_increment_id' => 'increment_id']
            );
        }
    }
```

These are the events which I used: `core_block_abstract_to_html_before` and `core_collection_abstract_load_before`. Please note that I do not want to add a new column for the recent orders grid just for the sales order grid. What should I change in my code ?

Thx

Comment: what is you column name in `'customer/entity'` table. because the right now it is looking for column name `increment_id`

Comment: increment_id. But  be aware there are orders increment_id and customer increment_id with the same column name.

Comment: try with `c.increment_id` they are not conflict but column name not correct. or did you create attribute for customer?

Comment: doesnt work. Is there a way to somehow make a difference between the 2 grids ?

Comment: FYI https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/301420/magento-grid-filter-condition-callback-ignored-in-magento-ver-1-9-4-3

Comment: ? $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best option, but it works (temporal coupling):

```
 private $grid;

 public function beforeBlockToHtml(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $this->grid = $observer->getBlock();
        /**
         * Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid
         */
        if ($this->grid instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid) {
            $this->grid ->addColumnAfter(
                'customer_increment_id',
                [
                    'header' => Mage::helper('ffm_codebin')->__('Customer Inc.'),
                    'index'  => 'customer_increment_id',
                    'filter_index' => 'c.increment_id'
                ],
                'entity_id'
            );
        }
    }
 public function beforeCollectionLoad(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $collection = $observer->getCollection();
        if(!isset($collection)){
            return;
        }

        if($collection instanceof Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Grid_Collection && $this->grid instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid){
            $collection->getSelect()->join(['c' => $collection->getTable('customer/entity')]
                ,'main_table.customer_id = c.entity_id', ['customer_increment_id' => 'c.increment_id']
            );
        }
    }
```