# Magento grid filter_condition_callback ignored? in Magento ver. 1.9.4.3

Tags: magento-1.9, grid, callback, openmage

Magento grid filter_condition_callback ignored? in Magento ver. 1.9.4.3

Help appreciated! Stuck ;)

We added a column to both the order and the product grid. This works fine. We then added a `filter_condition_callback` .. this has worked for years

Recently we updated to Magento ver. 1.9.4.3 the LTS version found here https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts

Since then `filter_condition_callback` seems to be completely ignored. We added an EXIT cluase in the method but nothing happens!

This is our code

```
            $block->addColumnAfter('warehouse',
                array(
                    'header' => Mage::helper('safemage_multiinventory')->__('Warehouse'),
                    'type'  => 'options',
                    'sortable' => false,
                    'index' => 'main_table.warehouse_ids',
                    'options' => $this->getActiveWarehousesArray(),
                    'frame_callback' => array($this, 'showWarehouseInOrder'),
                    'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, 'filterOrderWarehouseCondition'),
                    'width' => '120px'
                ),
                'shipping_name'
            );
```

and

```
    public function filterOrderWarehouseCondition($collection, $column)
    {
        if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
            return $this;
        }
        $select = $collection->getSelect();
        $select->joinLeft(
            array('warehouse_filter_tbl' => $collection->getTable('safemage_multiinventory/warehouse_order_item')),
            'warehouse_filter_tbl.order_id = main_table.entity_id AND warehouse_filter_tbl.qty <> 0',
            array());

        $collection->addFilter('warehouse_filter_tbl.warehouse_id', array('in' => $value));

        return $this;

    }
```

**question**: what is going on here and why is the callback method ignored? The strange thing is that we have other grids where the same callback seems to be accessed ... and here it works fine? duh??!

Tips and ideas welcome ;)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32222310/magento-invoice-grid-filter-condition-callback-not-working

complete trace, but here it can be seen that Magento makes no effort to find and use the `filter_condition_callback`

```
invalid attribute name: warehouse_ids

#0 app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(1295): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Invalid attribu...')
#1 app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(1388): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->_addAttributeJoin('warehouse_ids', 'inner')
#2 app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(322): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->_getAttributeConditionSql('warehouse_ids', Array, 'inner')
#3 app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php(1446): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->addAttributeToFilter('warehouse_ids', Array, 'inner')
#4 app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(342): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection->addAttributeToFilter('warehouse_ids', Array)
#5 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(472): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->addFieldToFilter('warehouse_ids', Array)
#6 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php(142): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_addColumnFilterToCollection(Object(Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column))
#7 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(457): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid->_addColumnFilterToCollection(Object(Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column))
#8 app/code/community/BL/CustomGrid/Model/Grid/Rewriter/Eval.php(39) : eval()'d code(88): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_setFilterValues(Array)
#9 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(534): BL_CustomGrid_Block_Rewrite_Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid->_setFilterValues(Array)
#10 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php(125): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#11 app/code/community/BL/CustomGrid/Model/Grid/Rewriter/Eval.php(39) : eval()'d code(107): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#12 app/code/community/BL/CustomGrid/Model/Grid/Rewriter/Eval.php(39) : eval()'d code(434): BL_CustomGrid_Block_Rewrite_Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#13 app/code/community/BL/CustomGrid/Model/Observer.php(500): BL_CustomGrid_Block_Rewrite_Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid->blcg_finishPrepareCollection()
#14 app/code/community/BL/CustomGrid/Model/Grid/Rewriter/Eval.php(39) : eval()'d code(104): BL_CustomGrid_Model_Observer->afterGridPrepareCollection(Object(BL_CustomGrid_Block_Rewrite_Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid))
#15 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(644): BL_CustomGrid_Block_Rewrite_Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#16 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(651): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareGrid()
#17 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(926): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_beforeToHtml()
#18 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#19 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(927): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#20 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#21 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#22 app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php(307): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#23 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController->gridAction()
#24 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('grid')
#25 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(174): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#26 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(381): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#27 app/Mage.php(745): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#28 index.php(109): Mage::run('STORENAME', 'store')
#29 {main}
```

Comment: Refer answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32222310/magento-invoice-grid-filter-condition-callback-not-working

Comment: Thx but method prepare collection is then unknown

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SUPEE-11219 Potential issues?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/292092/supee-11219-potential-issues)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There was a code breaking change

Read

https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/issues/882

And apply

https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/pull/887

Answer (score 0):

@snh_nl this [PR](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/301699/46249) did not went in, it should be fixed on client/module side ...see [SUPEE-11219 Potential issues?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/292092/supee-11219-potential-issues/292307#292307)

Also for OpenMage you have to *fix your code*!